# Зачем добавлять noexcept к функциям с constexpr?

Tags: c++

В стандартной библиотеке MSVC 2017 поставляется примерно такая реализация `std::size`:

```
template<class T, size_t S>
constexpr size_t size(T(&)[S]) noexcept
{
    return S;
}
```

Действительно, стандарт **не** запрещает функциям `constexpr` бросать исключения, но здесь и функция тривиальная. Компилятор может и сам вычислить `noexcept`, в других случаях MSVC 2017 прекрасно это делает, например:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto Plus(T left, T right)
{
     return left + right;
}

static_assert(noexcept(Plus(1,3)), "fail"); // OK в MSVC 2017
```

Тогда зачем `noexcept`: просто так захотелось, так надо, или это ошибка?

Comment: Кстати, gcc тоже жрёт этот `assert`, а вот `clang` проваливает. Всё-таки надо добавлять `noexcept(noexcept(left + right))` к функции, имхо.

Answer (score 5):

Начиная с С++17 `noexcept` входит в тип функции, но при этом как и возвращаемый тип, не является частью сигнатуры. Поэтому и требуется явное указание, если нужно чтобы функция действительно считалась `noexcept`.

Например, данный код валиден только начиная с c++17:

```
void f() noexcept {}

int main()
{
    using P = void (*)() noexcept; // c++14 не позволяет тут `noexcept`
    P fp = &f;
}
```

Это позволяет в частности делать такое разделение:

```
void g() {} 

P fp = &f;
P gp = &g;  // ошибка из-за отсутствия `noexcept` у `g`
```

Наличие `constexpr` у функции не даёт каких-либо преференций считать её `noexcept`. Хотя до c++17 нечто подобное [предполагалось](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/noexcept) при использовании оператора `noexcept`.

Comment: То есть указетль с `noexcept` неявно приводится к указателю без него, а наоброт неявно нет?

Comment: @Cerbo Да. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13df8617ef3c9457